# iOS : Change the text for zxing scanning event which says "Place barcode in box to scan"

Tags: ios, zxing

There is a text which displays "Place bar code in box to scan" when camera is started to scan the QR code. I want to change that text to "Place bar code / QR code in box to scan." From where can I change that in iOS. I am using ZXing library for QR code scanner.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in ZXing folder try to find file Localizable.strings for .en locale, there is a bunch of strings you can update.

Comment: did not find localizable.strings @Denis

Answer (score 0):

I got the text in Overlay.m file and edited these two lines (line no. 147 & 148)

```
char *text = "Place a QRcode inside the";
char *text2 = "viewfinder rectangle to scan it.";
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the `OverlayView.m` in the imported `ZXingWidget.project/Classes` folder. In `drawRect` method, you will see the text `"Place a barcode ..."`. Just change it to whatever you want.